# Save & Open Dialog - file order is now alphabetical, don't know why (edited)

Tags: 16.04, dialog

Something shifted and I don't know how to shift it back. In any program, when I open a save dialog or open dialog, the contents of the directory are listed alphabetically instead of the default...[altered information] subdirectories first, followed by files in alphabetical order. The way that the dialog box looks to me now is that the subdirectories are interspersed with the files, all in alphabetical order [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zjqbl.png). I am unable to figure out how to change the order of the directory contents. I am running Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS

Comment: Can you give an app example where this occurs? Can you post a screenshot? I don't see a file type column in open/save dialogs.

Comment: I mis-wrote the original post, I have edited it to clarify: The subdirectories are now mixed in with the files instead of being listed first. I will add a screenshot, now.

Answer (score 5):

In open/save file dialog box, right click on any of the items (files/folders) to open up a menu. Tick `Sort Folders before Files`. This thing was annoying me in Ubuntu 20.04 with Nautilus removed altogether.

Comment: Was not removed: it is in the preferences

Comment: I meant: OS is Ubuntu but I do not have Nautilus installed i.e. removed it.

Answer (score 2):

In both standard open/save dialogs, and in the Nautilus file manager, the process is the same... click on the column title to sort ascending/descending by that column. Clicking the column title a second time flips its sort up/down.

If you're not able to do this, the application that you're using may use its own special open/save dialog code that you can't change.

update:

In Nautilus file manager, to alpha sort and put folders before individual files, open a Nautilus window, go to the Preferences menu, and select "Sort folders before files".

Comment: File type is not an option because there is no column  It is not so much the files that I am interested in, it is the fact that subdirectories are listed within the alphabetical list instead of at the top of the list. As I write this out, I am realizing that I still want the file listing to be alphabetical, but I want the subdirectories above the files.

Comment: I was able to edit Nautilus by using the dconf-editor and now it is showing correctly in many programs including LibreOffice, Gimp and Brackets. But, when I use Firefox or Chrome, it is not showing directories first and then files when I open a dialog box. If it makes a difference, I am using Ubuntu Studio which seems to have minor differences in some things.